CSVアップロードした記事のカスタムタクソノミーに任意のスラッグを設定する方法
質問内容
以下の条件を満たす方法（function.phpに条件を満たすための関数を追加する想定）についてご教示いただけると幸いです。

Really Simple CSV ImporterというプラグインでCSV入稿する記事に付与するカスタムタクソノミーに対し、日本語のターム名（CSV上のカラム：tax_actress）と半角英数のスラッグ（CSV上のカラム：actress_slug）を自動的に設定する方法
カスタムタクソノミーは記事によって1つのみ設定する場合と複数設定する場合があり、複数の場合はカンマ区切りでタームをCSVデータに含めてアップする想定です
アップロードされた女優名がすでに存在していた場合はスラッグを更新、なければ新たにタームを追加するロジックですとなお望ましいです

目的
動画作品をまとめたサイトの実装のために女優一覧ページを用意し、その女優の出演作品を一覧表示する仕様を考えています。
そこでURLを"ドメイン/actress/{$女優名スラッグ}"という形式で表示したく、そのためのスラッグを半角英数で追加したいと考えております。
提供素材
サンプルCSVキャプチャ
https://gyazo.com/5701eea8020257a106ead315bbfb0249
WordPress環境

テーマ：Cocoon（child）
利用プラグイン：

Really Simple CSV Importer (記事データをCSV入稿する際に利用)
ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)



